# Иерархия пользователей

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, на wordpress у пользователей есть личный кабинет, через который они могут пригласить других пользователей.
Как можно потом эту связь просмотреть, т.е. чтобы можно было просмотреть в хронологи кто кого пригласил? Это можно организовать с помощью таблиц `wp_users` и `wp_usermeta`?

**P.S.**
т.е. нужно чтобы в админке можно было просматривать такую иерархию.
Допустим будет таблица юзеров, кликая по любому юзеру будет показываться кого он пригласил, и кто его пригласил, только как это организовать, ещё не придумал

Comment: Ну а какие проблемы поместить список приглашённых в usermeta?

Comment: @KAGG Design, дело в том, что пользователь может пригласить только одного друга и так по цепочке. И нужно отследить начиная с любого звена цепочки

Comment: т.е. если взять друга, которого пригласили, как узнать, кто его пригласил?

Comment: Все просто, в 1-м случае ищешь юзермету у текущего юзера, во 2-м ищещшь текущего юзера в юзермете.....

Comment: @Krya, это получается нужно просмотреть всех юзеров, чтобы найти текущего юзера? а проще можно?

Comment: Зачем смотреть всех юзеров? в 1-м get_user_meta, во 2-м запрос в таблицу user_meta и все

Comment: Можно записывать всю цепочку целиком для конкретного пользователя через строку типа 1.2.14.44. Когда пользователь создается, ID пригласившего добавляется в конец строки. А чтобы проверить всех, кого кто-то пригласил, использовать запрос типа LIKE.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov дичь какая-то....Добавился новый пользователь и тебе придется обновить у всех родительских это поле...Зачем делать лишнюю головную боль?

Comment: @Krya, ` в 1-м get_user_meta, во 2-м запрос в таблицу user_meta и все`,  а чем get_user_meta отличается от user_meta ? разве это не одно и тоже? можно подробней?